# Как выбирать данные исходя из заданного аргумента?

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть некий аргумент, и хочу выбирать данные исходя из этого аргумента:

```
    import sqlite3
    
    connection = sqlite3.connect('car_model.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars (
           car_id VARCHAR,  
           model VARCHAR,
           price VARCHAR
           )""")
    
    model = 'Hundai'
    price = 12000
    
    
    cursor.execute('''
    select * from cars where model is(?, ?)

''', (model))



cursor.execute('''                  
select * from cars where model = %s, (model)''')

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Никак не получается добавить аргумент в  комманду вставки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cursor.execute('''                  
select * from cars where model = %s, (model)''')
```

Данный вариант не работает по двум причинам

1. у вас ошибка в запросе. Должно быть так: `cursor.execute('''                   select * from cars where model = %s''', (model, ))`
2. вы передаете в качестве параметров одну переменную `(model)` вместо ожидаемого кортежа `(model, )`.

```
In [123]: print(type( (model) ))
<class 'str'>

In [124]: print(type( (model,) ))
<class 'tuple'>
```

Обратите внимание на запятую...

---

Пример использования параметризированных запросов:

```
qry = "insert into cars(car_id, model, price) values(?, ?, ?)"
records = [[1, "Hundai", 12000], [2, "BMW", 25000]]
cursor.executemany(qry, records)
connection.commit()
```

далее выбираем данные в запросе:

```
qry2 = "select * from cars where model = ?"
cursor.execute(qry2, (model, ))
res = list(cursor.fetchall())
```

результат:

```
In [122]: res
Out[122]: [('1', 'Hundai', '12000')]
```

Comment: Он не этого хочет :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, это полностью рабочий пример, показывающий как заполнять таблицу и как потом делать из нее запросы. Везде используются параметризованные запросы, которые не позволят воспользоваться "SQL Injections" )

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ!!!!!!!!!!